# Outlook Addin - How can I get Importance level of an email

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am creating a javascript Outlook addin which on ItemSend, obtains information on the email that is being sent. I want to get the Importance level of the email (if it is normal, low or high) however I cannot find how to do this.

I looked over the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook?view=outlook-js-preview but did not find any reference to Importance anywhere

Comment: Please see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62680610/), and related responses.

Answer (score 0):

The Office JavaScript API doesn't provide any property or method for getting or setting the priority of Outlook items. Nothing has been changed so far. You can use EWS or Graph API for setting the property. See [Call web services from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services) for more information.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

Comment: I am trying to get the importance flag not set it. I thought there may be a way of getting it but could not find it. Maybe it's part of the header or something

Comment: Nope, it doesn't matter setting or getting it. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: Eugene's answer is correct - there is no direct JS API for this yet and submitting/upvoting a request on Tech Community is the way to go. However for completeness, there IS a way to figure this out without a service call - using the getAllInternetHeadersAsync API. That will return all the internet headers in one big blob, and you could write some JS code to extract the value of importance header - that would give you what you're looking for. Not the most convenient way, but fastest (all on client).